# PowerShell conditionally fetches specific values from Json object

Tags: json, powershell

I use the REST API to get the return value, after converting the return value to json, I want to get the value I want from the json object, but I still can't achieve it.

My Json content `GetChangesInfo` like:

```
{
    "changeCounts":  {
                         "Edit":  4
                     },
    "changes":  [
                    {
                        "item":  {
                                     "objectId":  "7e852ad6d76de5xxxxxx92",
                                     "originalObjectId":  "c776929384xxxxx7912bf7",
                                     "gitObjectType":  "tree",
                                     "commitId":  "a73b19232650fcbxxxxxb6d4a6c969",
                                     "path":  "/pipeline",
                                     "isFolder":  true,
                                     "url":  "https://dev.azure.com/xxx"
                                 },
                        "changeType":  "edit"
                    },

                                     "originalObjectId":  "98a11c2fe81xxxx089fc62e986",
                                     "gitObjectType":  "blob",
                                     "commitId":  "a73b19232650fcxxxx6d4a6c969",
                                     "path":  "/pipeline/PL_xxxxx_START.json",
                                     "url":  "https://dev.azure.com/xxx"
                                 },
                        "changeType":  "edit"
                    },
                    {
                        "item":  {
                                     "objectId":  "7b3cfd336cxxxed652446",
                                     "originalObjectId":  "a67b91d65dxxxx579c4605143",
                                     "gitObjectType":  "tree",
                                     "commitId":  "a73b19232650fcbaxxxxb6d4a6c969",
                                     "path":  "/trigger",
                                     "isFolder":  true,
                                     "url":  "https://dev.azure.com/xxx"
                                 },
                        "changeType":  "edit"
                    },
                    {
                        "item":  {
                                     "objectId":  "13e6685cddc9xxxx68d9e159",
                                     "originalObjectId":  "48d0cf8338dfxxxx619a43064",
                                     "gitObjectType":  "blob",
                                     "commitId":  "a73b19232650xxxb6d4a6c969",
                                     "path":  "/trigger/TRIGGER_xxxx_WKLY.json",
                                     "url":  "https://dev.azure.com/xxx"
                                 },
                        "changeType":  "edit"
                    }
                ]
}
```

What I want to get is the value of the `"path":  "/trigger/TRIGGER_Test.json"` instead of `"path":  "/trigger"`.

So, I using following code with the filter `Where-Object {($_.item -notcontains 'isFolder')}` to get the value:

```
$GetChanges = "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxx/commits/xxx/changes?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$GetChangesInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetChanges -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

$GetChangesInfo = $($GetChangesInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)

$darts = $GetChangesInfo.changes | Where-Object {($_.item -notcontains 'isFolder')}

Write-Host "This is_$darts"
```

Because `changes` contain the same node `item`, `path`. But I need to contain only the file name of the specific file, **not the folder**.

So I use it as a filter according to whether the `isFolder` node is included under the `item`.

But I do not get the value. Please help.

Result:

```
This is_
```

**Update:**

Now, I could get the all the paths, like:

```
/DB/main/StoredProcedure/DB_Test.sql
/trigger/TRIGGER_Test.json
/notebooks/HKAZEDDB0002/BASIS/NoteBook_Test.py
/pipeline/PL_Test2.json
/pipeline/PL_Test.json
```

I want to filter all above paths not including the folder `/main`, the first path value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right this should be enough ...

```
$GetChangesInfo = @'
{
    "changeCounts": {
        "Edit": 1,
        "Add": 1
    },
    "changes": [
        {
            "item": {
                "path": "/trigger",
                "isFolder": true,
            },
            "changeType": "edit"
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "path": "/trigger/TRIGGER_Test.json",
            },
            "changeType": "add"
        }
    ]
}
'@ |
    ConvertFrom-Json

$darts = $GetChangesInfo.changes | Where-Object {-not $_.item.isFolder} 
$darts.item.path
```

I removed the not necessary parts of your JSON.

For your path check ... the simplest approach would be to use `-match` or `-notmatch`

```
$PathList = 
'/DB/main/StoredProcedure/DB_Test.sql',
'/trigger/TRIGGER_Test.json',
'/notebooks/HKAZEDDB0002/BASIS/NoteBook_Test.py',
'/pipeline/PL_Test2.json',
'/pipeline/PL_Test.json'

$PathList |
    Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '/main'}
```

Comment: It works for me! Thanks. By the way,  the `$darts.item.path` will return the value of the path, is there an easy way to check that the path contains a specific folder, I need the filenames in the specific folder to be stripped from the overall?

Comment: Yes, I want to exclude some files name from the specify foder, like main, that because that is sql files, we do not want to check. So, I need to exclude them. I update the  question, would you please help me to if statement to exclude the main folder？ Thanks. You could update it in your answer.

Comment: I thought you meant the other way around ... added an example how to check for not having a part of a certain path.

Comment: I want to use this as the judgment statement of if, anyway, I have worked it out. Thank you for your help and patience, you saved my life!

Comment: The solution will not work when we have more one `item` , you could checkmy update Json file.